# Trying to create a shopping cart in windows form c#. Specifically, adding a new row into datagridview from a button click in another form

Tags: c#, datagridview

a super beginner here.

I'm trying to create a shopping cart function in Windows Form C#

I have a form called `Shopping_Cart` with a datagridview called `cartlist`.

and I have a seperate form which contains my products called `Meat` which contains a button to add to cart below each of the products with a textbox `BeefQty` for quantity.

By the way, the `Shopping_Cart` and `Meat` pages are opened through a button from a side panel and are brought to front in the designated space in the window, so my app basically runs in a single window.

What I want to do is, when I click the add button, it will add row into `cartlist` in the other form without needing to open the `Shopping_Cart` in a new window.

All the solutions I've searched up thus far includes opening an instance of the other form the button click which I do not want to do.

What I have tried.

In the `Meat` form

```
private void AddBeefBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cartlist.ColumnCount = 3;
            cartlist.Columns[0].Name = "Item";
            cartlist.Columns[1].Name = "Quantity";
            cartlist.Columns[2].Name = "Price";

            string[] row = new string[] { "Beef", "BeefQty.text", "10*BeefQty.text" };
            cartlist.Rows.Add(row);
        }
```

It gave me error saying that `CS0103 : The name 'cartlist' does not exist in the current context` which I don't understand since cartlist does exist in the `Shopping_Cart` form.

Do note that I have absolutely zero experience with C# and Windows Form and that I could care less about OOP concepts right now and I just want the app to function as it should.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your information, the reason that you're receiving `CS0103 : The name 'cartlist' does not exist in the current` is due to the fact that `cartlist` exists in `Shopping_Cart` but not in `Meat`. They do not share `cartlist`, hence the error.

The simplest way to resolve this issue is to create a `BindingList` in a shared class, and bind this list to the `cartlist` data source.

**Given**

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace Test
{
    // Model to use to fill the rows of the DataGridView
    public class ItemModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string item;
        private decimal qty, price;

        public string Item
        {
            get => item;
            set { item = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        public decimal Quantity
        {
            get => qty;
            set { qty = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        public decimal Price
        {
            get => price;
            set { price = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        
        // This is to notify the grid if any of the properties are updated
        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

We can create a shared class like this to store the `BindingList`:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Test
{
    public static class SharedData
    {
        public static BindingList<ItemModel> Items { get; set; } = new BindingList<ItemModel>();
    }
}
```

From here, we would setup the form with the `DataGridView` like so:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class ShoppingCart : Form
    {
        public ShoppingCart()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
            // Note how we are calling SharedData here
            ItemDataGridView.DataSource = SharedData.Items;
        }
    }
}
```

And we can add to the `BindingList` like:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class Meat : Form
    {
        public Meat()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void AddBeefBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ItemModel model = new ItemModel
            {
                Item = "Beef",
                Quantity = 10M,
                Price = 9.95M,
            };

            SharedData.Items.Add(model);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image: Windows Form output of code above]

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I do have a question. In the AddBeefBtn, is it possible to retrieve the value for Quantity from a textbox in the form? And to have the price totaled with say: Price= 10*Quantity?

Comment: @Blewbles yes you can. To retrieve the string value of a textbox, you'd just need to do something like `textBox1.Text`, which will retrieve the string value. If you want to convert a string into a decimal, look at `decimal.TryParse` on google